# Uploading data to Azure App Service's persistent storage (%HOME%)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a windows-based app service that requires a large dataset to run (files stored on Azure Blob Storage at around ~30GB). This data is static per app version, and therefore should be accessible to all instances across a given slot (a slot in our case represents a version).

Based on our initial research, it seems like Persistent Storage (%HOME%) would be the ideal place for this, since data stored there is shared across instances, but not across slots.

The next step now is to load the required data as part of our devops deployment pipeline, since the app service cannot operate without the underlying data. However, it seems like the %HOME% directory is only accessible by the app service itself, even though the underlying implementation is using Azure Storage.

At this point, we're considering having the app service download the data during its startup, but then we hit a snag which is that we have two instances. We could implement a Mutex (using blob lease) but this seems to us to be too complicated a solution for a simple need.

Any thoughts about how to best implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The problems I see with loading the file on container startup are the following:

1. It's going to be really slow, and you might hit one of the built-in App Service timeouts.
2. Every time your container restarts, or you add another instance, it will re-download all the data, and it might cause issues with blocked writes because of file handle locks, which can make files or directories on %HOME% completely unaccessible for reading and modifying (I just had this happen to me).

For this I would rather suggest connecting the app to Azure Files by SMB, and for example have a directory per each version. This way you can connect to Azure Files and write the data during your build pipeline, and save an ENV variable or file that tells each slot which directory to get the current version's data from.